# Understanding the Different Properties of Lambda Calculus

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

So I am currently learning about lambda calculus in my computer science class, and really having trouble understanding the various properties and operations thereof. There is a great post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140819/lambda-calculus-reduction-steps) explaining the basic ideas of lambda calculus and how it works -- and I can understand that much: the basic concept; but I am having a great deal of trouble applying it past very simple problems (E.G. $\ \lambda x.x $).

Can someone give a simple explanation for the operations of more complex lambda calculus problems (reduction)? I have a few particular things in mind:

1. How do variables apply to multiple functions? E.G. $\ \lambda x.\lambda z .\lambda y . (x \space \space y) $
2. How do parentheses play out in reduction? E.G. How is $\ (\lambda y.y) \space (\lambda x.\lambda z.z) \space w \space$ properly reduced, and why?
3. What does it mean when a  variable comes before a lambda function? E.G. $\ y \space (\lambda x.x \space z) $
4. What does it mean for a function to have a multi-variable name? Is it just completely arbitrary? E.G. could $\ \lambda xyz.w \space$ just as easily be called $\ \lambda x.w \space$, or is there some significance to a multivariable function pass ($\ \lambda xyz \space$)?
5. Are variable names outside of parentheses arbitrary in comparison to the variable names inside parentheses? E.G. Could  $\ (\lambda x.x \space y) \space x \space$ just as easily be written as $\ (\lambda z.z \space y) \space x $ without the meaning changing (no particular relationship between the x's inside the parentheses and the x outside the parentheses)?

This is not, I suppose, an exhaustive list, and if there are any other tricky things about lambda calculus I should know, I would much appreciate a comment/edit. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: $\lambda xyz.\!w$ is usually an abbreviation for $\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\! \lambda z.\! w$.

Comment: It's difficult to answer so many questions at the same time. The natural answer to your current post would be essentially a copy of what you can read on [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) on $\lambda$-calculus (Have you read it? It might be very useful to you). Please, try to focus on only one specific question per post.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I have read the Wikipedia page on λ -calculus, and it does not answer the questions I have asked above. Just like every other resource I have found online, all the examples on the page are very basic, and do not cover the things I have asked above.

Comment: About 3, where did you see it? it would be helpful to have an example of it.

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps you don't understand the basic syntax of $\lambda$-terms.  A $\lambda$-term has one of three forms: A variable, such as $y$. An _abstraction_, which has the form $\lambda v.\!T$, where $v$ is a variable and $T$ is a $\lambda$-term. Or an _application_ $(P\ Q)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are $\lambda$-terms. So for example, $\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\!z$ is an abstraction, where the parameter variable is $x$ and the body term is $\lambda y.\!z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How do variables apply to multiple functions? E.G. $\ \lambda x.\lambda z .\lambda y . (x \space \space y) $

I don't understand what you are asking, but perhaps an example will help:

$$(\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\!x)\ q\ r \\
(\lambda y.\!q)\ r \\
q
$$

$$(\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\!y)\ q\ r \\
(\lambda y.\!y)\ r \\
r
$$

> 2. How do parentheses play out in reduction? E.G. How is $\ (\lambda y.y) \space (\lambda x.\lambda z.z) \space w \space$ properly reduced, and why?

Application is normally understood to “associate to the left”, so that $$A\ B\ C$$ is actually short for $$(A\ B)\ C.$$

$\ (\lambda y.y) \space (\lambda x.\lambda z.z) \space w \space$ should be read as an abbreviation for
$((\lambda y.y) \space (\lambda x.\lambda z.z)) \space w \space$,
which reduces as follows:

$$ \color{darkblue}{((\lambda y.y) \space (\lambda x.\lambda z.z))} \space w\\
(\lambda x.\lambda z.z) \space w \\
\lambda z.z
$$

> 3. What does it mean when a  variable comes before a lambda function? E.G. $\ y \space (\lambda x.x \space z) $

It means that the term $y$ is being applied to the term $(\lambda x.x \space z)$.  This term can't be reduced further.  If the symbol “$y$” was not actually a $\lambda$-term but a previously-agreed abbreviation for a $\lambda$-term, we could at this point replace it with its definition and perhaps proceed with the reduction.

> 4. What does it mean for a function to have a multi-variable name? Is it just completely arbitrary? E.G. could $\ \lambda xyz.w \space$ just as easily be called $\ \lambda x.w \space$, or is there some significance to a multivariable function pass ($\ \lambda xyz \space$)?

This question is phrased very strangely.  The “$xyz$” is not the name of a function. Usually the variable names we write are single letters, and $\lambda xyz.\!w$ is understood to be an abbreviation for $\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\!\lambda z.\! w$.  So for example $(\lambda xyz.\!w) t$ reduces to $\lambda yz.\! w$ and $(\lambda xyz.\!x) t$ reduces to $\lambda yz.\! t$.

> 5. Are variable names outside of parentheses arbitrary in comparison to the variable names inside parentheses? E.G. Could  $\ (\lambda x.x \space y) \space x \space$ just as easily be written as $\ (\lambda z.z \space y) \space x $ without the meaning changing (no particular relationship between the x's inside the parentheses and the x outside the parentheses)?

The parentheses are not the important thing here.  (Your understanding of the syntax of $\lambda$-terms is a little wonky.)  In $\lambda z.\!z y$ we say that the variable $z$ is *bound* and the variable $y$ is *free*.  And your intuition is correct:  the names of bound variables are unimportant.  The term $\ (\lambda x.x \space y) \space x \space$ is completely equivalent to the term $\ (\lambda z.z \space y) \space x \space$ under a process called [$\alpha$-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B1-conversion); the terms are said to be $\alpha$-equivalent.  This is analogous to the way the notations “$\frac12$” and “$\frac36$” are considered to represent the exact same object, just written in two different ways.

You may want to try reading the first few chapters of Henk Barendregt's book *The Lambda Calculus*, which lays out all of this carefully and in as much detail as you could want.

Comment: As for 1, I think OP thinks that something is being applied in their example $\lambda x.\lambda y. \lambda z. (x y)$, while in reality the $(x y)$ is the "output" of their lambda term after eating three variables.

Comment: I do have a question about your answer to number two, which is: why does (λx.λz.z) w reduce to λz.z? Isn't (λx.λz.z) w saying "(a function with inputs x and z that returns z) w", meaning that we would reduce this to "(λz.z) w", which is to say "a function with input z that returns z; apply w to the function", meaning that we would apply w to λz.z, thus returning w? Thank you SO much for your incredibly helpful post, by the way!

Comment: You should understand $\lambda x.\!\lambda z.\!z$ as meaning $\lambda x.\!(\lambda z.\!z)$, but we omit the parentheses. $\lambda x.\!T$ models a function that takes an argument, say $w$, and returns a version of $T$ in which $x$  was replaced by $w$. The term $\lambda x.\!\lambda z.\!z$ is the case of this where the term $T$ is $\lambda z.\!z$. This $\lambda x.\!\lambda z.\!z$ models a function that takes an argument $w$ and returns $\!\lambda z.\!z$, but with $x$ replaced by $w$. But  $\!\lambda z.\!z$ with $x$ replaced by $w$ is just $\!\lambda z.\!z$ because it has no $x$ to replace.

Comment: (The same thing is going on in example 1.)

Comment: (Also in example 4.)

Comment: @MJD oooh, that totally makes sense, thank you so much!